# Do I need to know how to manually create data structures for getting entry level job or should i just know how to use those from collection framework?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, structure

As I know so far, there are two ways to use data structures - use one from collection framework (like: `LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();`) or to create those structures manually (like: `public class Node<T>{T data; Node Next; public Node(T data) {this.data = data;}}` and then: `public class LinkedList <T>{Node head;` -and corresponding methods like `add`, `remove`...) and then to add methods to them (like: `add`, `push`, `pop`, etc...)

Comment: A job is never going to ask you to write a linked list class. You will be expected to understand the performance characteristics of the `java.util` implementations of `List` (and `Set` and `Map`), and how to to use them in a type-safe and thread-safe manner, and which implementations to use if you want particular ordering.

Comment: (and why hashCode and equals are important)

Answer (score 1):

There is a fair bit to unpick in this question.

On the one hand, it is unlikely that you will be required to re-implement `LinkedList` as part of your actual job.  Certainly, not in Java, and with the exact same API and functionality as `LinkedList`.  (That would be a waste of time!)

But you might need to implement:

- a custom Java linked list with an API that is incompatible with the `java.util.List` API
- an "open" linked list as part of something else where the nodes are actually the list elements<sup>1</sup>
- a linked list in another programming language<sup>2</sup> (e.g. C or assembly language)

Furthermore, there are other reasons for your course teaching you about linked lists:

- Understanding how linked lists work helps you understand their performance characteristics, and their implementation trade-offs ... independently of any particular programming language.
- This is a "vehicle" for teaching you about some other important topics; e.g. reasoning about code, complexity theory, abstraction, etc.

Your teacher setting you an exercise to *implement* a linked list class has the *additional* benefit of getting you more proficient at programming in general.  That will definitely serve you in good stead when you come to get your first job.

Yes Marko, as part of the job application / interview process, you are likely to be tested on your practical programming and problem solving skills.  Especially for an entry level position.

They probably won't ask you to code a linked list in the job interview<sup>3</sup>.  So *memorizing* a linked list implementation is a waste of time, IMO.  Instead, practice solving problems you haven't seen / been taught.  That's a better way to build up your skills.

Finally, in the competitive marketplace of people applying for their first job, things that will impress at a job interview (such as good understanding of data structures) will give you an advantage over the "straight C" new graduate programmers in your cohort.

---

<sup>1 - You might do this for performance related reasons in a performance critical application.

2 - Don't imagine that the only programming language that you will use in your career will be Java.

3 - If they do, that is an indication that your interviewer is uninspired or lazy ... which is not a good sign.</sup>